# angular 2 focus element after router.navigate is not working

Tags: angular, angular-routing

On certain event I need to navigate to different route and focus one of the input filed.

My Template

```
<qualification>

<address (updateAddress)="updateAddress($event);"> 

</address>

</qualification>
```

In address component html one of the button

```
<span class="filter-address" (click)="updateAddressClicked()">Update Address </span>
```

In address component

```
@Output() updateAddress = new EventEmitter();
updateAddressClicked($event){
     this.router.navigate(['/page/one'], {preserveQueryParams: true})
     this.updateAddress.emit(true);
}
```

In qualification component I have defined `vc` as

```
@ViewChildren('inputone') vc;
```

html on qualificatioin

```
<input #inputone name="inputone">
```

and

```
updateAddress($event){
    this.vc.first.nativeElement.focus()
}
```

When I am in /page/one route and navigate to /page/one route (i.e. itself) focus works. But if I am in different route lets say /page/two then when event triggers navigation to /page/one is fine but I get error which says

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'nativeElement' of undefined

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In which lifecycle event is the focus code being called? Can you show the full component code?

Comment: focus code is in function, which is triggered after the event in another component.

Comment: @JayChase I have updated the OP

Comment: Is the VC control in the component that you are routing to or your current component

Comment: its in the component that I am routing to. @Baconbeastnz

Comment: You need to call this.vc.first.nativeElement.focus() from the component you are routing to then, not the current component.

Comment: I tried that as well, result is same.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your current component:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(['/page/one?event=true'], {preserveQueryParams: true})
```

Then in your component you are routing to do this.

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
    (param: any) => {
    let event = param['event'];
    if(event) {
      this.vc.first.nativeElement.focus();
    }
 });
}
```

That should allow you to conditionally focus based on the existence of the event queryparam.

Comment: but i need to call it only after event is triggered, so normal routing won't focus the input, only when there is special event I need to change the route and focus the input

Comment: as there any reason you are using param['event'], I am not passing any variable related to event in parameter.

Comment: That's so you can conditionally trigger your input focus as you mentioned you only want it to occur after that event. You could use a double bound variable that is shared between two components as your basis for conditional execution but without seeing your code I can't really help. Or you could just set an item and clear it in localStorage.